# How to calculate stream order from vector data in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I know that NVision Solutions has a tool for calculating stream order from vector hydrography data for ArcGIS 9.3.1. Is there something similar that works with ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 2):

Pete,

We've just updated our free StreamVector tool for ArcGIS 10:

http://store.nvisionsolutions.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8_2&products_id=3

Comment: See my warning about this tool [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22735/how-to-calculate-stream-order-for-vector-data-without-a-dem).